# Error in installation of npm packages

Tags: android, node.js, npm, remote-debugging, weinre

when trying to install browser-sync I get the following [error](http://pastebin.ca/3059524) on my windows command prompt.

then i tried to install weinre and I get the following [error](http://pastebin.ca/3059526) on my windows command prompt.

when I navigate to  C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log as it suggests to look for the error log, I get the following [error](http://pastebin.ca/3059527).

I am very desperate to install and debug my web page on native android browser :(

Regards.

**EDIT:** I installed node.js using its default windows 64 bit installer.

Answer (score 0):

The first error page would seem to indicate an issue with compiling modules on Windows, given the node-gyp'ish errors.  Sorry, can't help there.

The second error page is one I've seen reported before with weinre, but am not sure what the problem actually is at this point.  Seems to be some kind of npm environmental issue.

In lieu of installing weinre, you can instead use a public weinre server, such as http://weinre.mybluemix.net/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't address the original issue asked about in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option is to use a better debugger than weinre.  See the yellow box on the page http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/ for information on debuggers available for different platforms.